# Running Time of Connected Component Count Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, graph, time-complexity

I've been looking into connected components, and came across this description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)):

> It is straightforward to compute the connected components of a graph
>   in linear time (in terms of the numbers of the vertices and edges of
>   the graph) using either breadth-first search or depth-first search. In
>   either case, a search that begins at some particular vertex v will
>   find the entire connected component containing v (and no more) before
>   returning. To find all the connected components of a graph, loop
>   through its vertices, starting a new breadth first or depth first
>   search whenever the loop reaches a vertex that has not already been
>   included in a previously found connected component.

What would be the run time of this operation? I've come across sources that say connected components are done in `O(n)` time. However, from what I can tell, in the worst case where each vertex is its own connected component, this algorithm will have to perform n DFS/BFS operations, each of which is itself `O(n)` time. Therefore, shouldn't the run time of this be `O(n^2)`?

Comment: If all vertices are disconnected then each of the BFS is going to end at its start vertex and thus be O(1). You've got to argue the other way around: any way you're searching, you'll never visit a vertex more than once, thus the whole operation is O(n)

Comment: DFS or BFS takes O(N) time, but that's a different N.  The sum of the sizes of all the connected components you have to trace equals the size of the whole graph.

Answer (score 11):

First, the traversing of a single connected component `G(V, E)` with `|V|` vertices and `|E|` edges using DFS or BFS has `O(|V|+|E|)` complexity.

> linear time (in terms of the numbers of the vertices and edges of the
>   graph)

Let's assume that graph `G(V, E)` has `k` connected components.

```
G(V, E) = G1(V1, E1) ∪ G2(V2, E2) ∪ ... ∪ Gk(Vk, Ek)
```

Every component `Gi` could be found with DFS/BFS in `O(|Vi|+|Ei|)`. As a result, the total time of the algorithm that for every not visited vertex starts a DFS or BFS to traverse its connected component is:

```
O(|V1|+|E1|) + O(|V2|+|E2|) + ... + O(|Vk|+|Ek|) + O(|V|)
```

These components have no any common vertex or edge because they are not connected. So:

```
|V| = |V1| + |V2| + ... + |Vk|
|E| = |E1| + |E2| + ... + |Ek|
```

Finally, the overall complexity of computation of connected components is:

```
O(|V1|+|E1|) + O(|V2|+|E2|) + ... + O(|Vk|+|Ek|) + O(|V|) =
O(|V1|+|V2|+...+|Vk| + |E1|+|E2|+...+|Ek|) + O(|V|) =
O(|V|+|E|) + O(|V|) =
O(|V|+|E|)
```